# Can uml state machine exist independent of an object?

Tags: uml

We are making a UML tool, it has an option for drawing class diagram, and drawing state machine diagram. You can draw state machine and class diagrams independently. Our supervisor says that it is not possible. If you draw state machine with no corresponding linkage with a class it is worthless. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would says Yes if you want a complete model...
A state machine describes the behavior of an Object so you have to clarify somehow which object the behavior describes.
**But** in several cases, this clarification can be not find in the model mainly because it is specified outside the model e.g. inside an external document or in a description.